# Is it possible to "intercept" a 3rd party library's "WriteFile" operation

Tags: c#, writefile

This is likely a long shot, but I thought I'd ask anyway.  I'm using a document management system's API.  They provide a "WriteFile" method to save a given document to disk.  However, the library does not have a way to simply read a document into memory.  My only option, it seems, is to write to disk, then read it back in again.  I'm wondering if there is a better way to work around this obvious limitation.

The method takes a string for the resulting file path.  Method signature:

```
void ImageInfo.WriteFile(string Filename);
```

Comment: What do you pass into their WriteFile API? A filename, or an open file?

Comment: @psmears: exactly what I was going to ask.

Comment: So your goal is to just avoid reading the file from disk? For perf reasons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theoretically, it is possible to intercept the WriteFile win32 API calls of any process, be it .NET, C++, etc using something called as [Import Address Table Hooking](http://sandsprite.com/CodeStuff/IAT_Hooking.html)  which actually is a valuable tool in software testing on windows.

Basically you could overwrite the WriteFile,kernel32.dll entry in the Import Address Table to point to your method and then intercept the bytes which are attempted to be written.

There are probably other ways in layers above, like in .NET where you could possibly change the ILASM code of the 3rd party app dll. Or have your own version of some of the .NET dlls which replace some of the standard .NET classes.

Practically, it might not really be worth it, for e.g. If the API does not explicitly flush the file to disk, your subsequent reads might end up coming from the OS file cache and won't be that big a perf problem. You could probably achieve this by creating the file and keeping it open before calling WriteFile (just a guess).

Of course, I suppose you have profiled and measured it already.

Answer (score 2):

You'd need a Windows API hooking library that can call a managed code callback.  [Easyhook](http://easyhook.codeplex.com/) is one such library.  Beware that you might out that you haven't gained anything after you're done, the file system cache already provides direct memory access to file data.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the API does not provide the reading part because they can't provide a better (more performant) manner than what is already available in the .NET framework.